# How do I wire this Leviton switch?

Tags: switch, bedroom, closet

I have a new Leviton Decora Switch with built in pilot light (Catalog # 5618-2W). I want to replace a switch currently connected to two black wires. Three sets of wires come into the box. Each set consists on a black, a white and a ground wire.

I know the ground wires go to the green screw.

On one side of the switch I have a black screw and a brass screw. On the other side I have a silver screw.

Comment: [Relevant wiring diagram.](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=3tGSzbJgP.BkeeUq8N.PZw)

Comment: I don't see the question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll start by connect the grounding conductor to the green screw. The black wires that are currently attached to the old switch, will attach to the black and brass colored screws on the new switch. Finally you'll have to locate a grounded "neutral" wire; or group of wires, within the box. Using a twist-on wire connector, connect a short bit of wire to the grounded "neutral" wire(s). Connect the other end of the short bit of wire, to the silver screw on the new switch.

[image: Wiring]

Comment: In the diagram, the **L** outside the box is the fixture or outlets (*Load*) that are controlled by the switch. The **L** inside the box is the lamp  that is on when the switch is on.

Comment: @bib Thanks, I'll update the image when I get a chance.